# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference in book listing app project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, adapter

I am making my project as part of my udacity curriculum of networking.I am getting the error at(   at `com.example.android.flavor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)).`
I don't know how to solve this one.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<BookList>> {
public static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

/**
 * Constant value for the Book loader ID. We can choose any integer.
 * This really only comes into play if you're using multiple loaders.
 */
private Adapter mAdapter;
private static final int BOOK_LOADER_ID = 1;

private String GOOGLE_BOOK_URL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Fetching the bundle from the searchbar activity
    Bundle searchBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String searchQuery = searchBundle.getString("searchQuery");
    searchQuery = searchQuery.replaceAll("","+");
    Log.v("replace",searchQuery);

    //Make a new String builder to produce URL
    StringBuilder searchUrlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    searchUrlBuilder.append("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + searchQuery +
    "&maxResults= 20");
    Log.v("URL", String.valueOf(searchUrlBuilder));
    //GOOG...URL assumes value of searchUrlBuilder
    GOOGLE_BOOK_URL = String.valueOf(searchUrlBuilder);


    // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
    final ListView bookListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_book);

    // Create a new adapter that takes an empty list of earthquakes as input
    mAdapter = new BookListAdapter(this, new ArrayList<BookList>());

    // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
    // so the list can be populated in the user interface
    bookListView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) mAdapter);

    //Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
    LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();

    // Initialize the loader. Pass in the int ID constant defined above and pass in null for
    // the bundle. Pass in this activity for the LoaderCallbacks parameter (which is valid
    // because this activity implements the LoaderCallbacks interface).
    loaderManager.initLoader(BOOK_LOADER_ID, null,  this);
}

@Override
public Loader<List<BookList>> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    //Create a new Loader for the given URL this is where GOOGLE_BOOKS_REQUEST_URL was
    return new BookLoader(this, GOOGLE_BOOK_URL);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<BookList>> loader, List<BookList> books) {
    //Clear the adapter of previous data
    books.clear();

    if (books != null && !books.isEmpty()) {
        books.addAll(books);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<BookList>> loader) {
    // Loader reset, so we can clear out our existing data.

}
```

}

Logcat:

```
enter code here

09-18 17:05:58.961 23093-23093/com.example.android.flavor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.android.flavor, PID: 23093
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.flavor/com.example.android.flavor.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.example.android.flavor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
```

Comment: post code in which you put your string bundle, please

Comment: Hey @firegloves can you be more specific, I don't know what you are asking?

Comment: To receive a Bundle in an Activity it means that when you launch this Activity you must have added that Bundle to the Intent. You must specify manually what to pass to the starting Activity. Reading your post I can imagine that your MainActivity is your first launched activity, is it right?

Comment: It say's character's are too long.Can I reply you with my "answer your question button".

Comment: edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To receive a Bundle in an Activity it means that when you launch this Activity you must have added that Bundle to the Intent. You must specify manually what to pass to the starting Activity. Reading your post I can imagine that your MainActivity is your first launched activity, is it right?

**Wrong method to pass Bundle**

You are passing wrong your Bundle to your Activity. Try this:

```
final Intent openResultActivity = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        final EditText searchQuery = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);

        Button searchButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.search_button);
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                final String searchQueryString=searchQuery.getText().toString();
                Log.v("SearchinSBA",searchQueryString);

                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("searchQuery",searchQueryString);
                openResultActivity.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(openResultActivity);
            }
        });
```

**Wrong LaunchActivity**

My first answer was correct: you are launching your app starting from `MainActivity`. So the code in `SearchBarActivity` (that one were you do `putString` etc.) is never executed. That code must be executed for first, so it can launch `MainActivity` passing your bundle to it.

Your problem resides in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. You must change your launcher activity as follow:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.flavor">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SearchBarActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you check my answer in the post?

Comment: Can you look into it because even after your editing it still didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

you are not receiving the bundle. Please check for null before access its method

```
String searchQuery;
if(searchBundle!=null){
   searchQuery = searchBundle.getString("searchQuery");
}
```

or if you are passing bundle incorrectly do this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("searchQuery", yourSearchQuery);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Now I am getting an error to initialize the searchQuery.Any other suggestions?